# Telerik RadTreeView And Client-Side Expand/Collapse

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, telerik, radtreeview

I'm following this approach to expanding and collapsing all nodes in client JavaScript: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/treeview/tree_expand_client_side.html

However, it's taking a  REALLY long time to process this, and after expanding then collapsing, I get the "script unresponsive" error, so I was wondering if there was a way to speed this up for a rather large tree?  Is there a better way to parse it?  Currently, the tree is 4 levels deep.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of your code too?

Comment: There's nothing special about it; it essentially programmably creates 621 nodes 4 levels deep from the server side... from the client, the code is exactly what's in the above link.

Comment: Have you tried just expanding all of the nodes server-side since you're already programmatically creating the nodes on the server? Shouldn't really be a performance hit and might be a better alternative here. As for this particular, there might be something specific with your particular implementation which is causing this, as similar tests on my machine work pretty well. Isolating this into a solution and submitting it in a support ticket over at Telerik will be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the "script unresponsive" errors by expanding and collapsing the tree asynchronously. In addition, I expand from the bottom (so you can see the nodes expand) and collapse from the top, but only when it gets to the last node in each branch, so visually it's far more interesting to the user. They can actually see it happen, and if it's not fast (IE7 and before is particularly slow), it's at least entertaining while they wait.

```
var treeView, nodes;

function expandAllNodesAsynchronously() {
    if (<%= expandedLoaded.ToString().ToLower() %>) {
        treeView = $find("<%= tv.ClientID %>");
        nodes = treeView.get_allNodes();
        if (nodes.length > 1) {
            doTheWork(expandOneNode, nodes.length);
        }
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

function expandOneNode(whichNode) {
    var actualNode = nodes.length - whichNode;
    if (nodes[actualNode].get_nextNode() == null) {
        nodes[actualNode].get_parent().expand();
    }
}

function collapseAllNodesAsynchronously() {
    treeView = $find("<%= tv.ClientID %>");
    nodes = treeView.get_allNodes();
    if (nodes.length > 1) {
        doTheWork(collapseOneNode, nodes.length);
    }
}

function collapseOneNode(whichNode) {
    if (nodes[whichNode].get_nextNode() == null && nodes[whichNode].get_parent() != nodes[0]) {
        nodes[whichNode].get_parent().collapse();
    }
}

function doTheWork(operation, cycles) { //, callback
    var self = this, // in case you need it
        cyclesComplete = 1,
        batchSize = 10; // Larger batch sizes will be slightly quicker, but visually choppier

    var doOneBatch = function() {
        var c = 0;
        while(cyclesComplete < cycles) {
            operation(cyclesComplete);
            c++;
            if(c >= batchSize) {
                // may need to store interim results here
                break;
            }
            cyclesComplete++;
        }
        if (cyclesComplete < cycles) {
            setTimeout(doOneBatch, 1); // "1" is the length of the delay in milliseconds
        }
        else {
            // Not necessary to do anything when done
            //callback(); // maybe pass results here
        }
    };

    // kickoff
    doOneBatch();
    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Start off getting your nodes with `yourtreeViewInstance.get_nodes()`, and then the child nodes as `eachChildNode.get_nodes()` and so on down the hierarchy.

Then you can expand each item by calling `.set_expanded(true);` on each node you want to expand.